# Changing shape of windows form and raise custom event

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, system.drawing

I am creating an application like "Rocket Dock. I want to

1) Change the default shape of the windows form. Like curve edges etc.
2) How can I raise event so that when I move cursor to the top of the screen, my app appears and when leave the interface it moves upward and disappear?

Comment: Use WPF, Winforms doesn't handle graphical stuff like that very well at all, whereas WPF was designed to do exactly that.

Comment: @SpikeX: I have successfully had 20-25 shaped forms on the screen at once (single .NET application) where each form was changing shape at 30 fps.  Winforms can handle it just fine.

Comment: Just because it works doesn't mean it's the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  There are a couple of ways to create a custom WinForm shape

1a)  Set the form's background to an image and use a transparency key:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289517%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

1b) Define a custom shape using System.Drawing and set the forms region to your newly created path:
http://codegod.org/WebAppCodeGod/Creating-Custom-Shapes-for-Forms-in-Windows-Forms-AID377.aspx

2) Collapse your form to a very small size and hook the MouseEnter (or MouseHover) event to trigger the "entering" effect.  You can hook the Form's MouseLeave event to trigger the "leaving" effect.